# What could be done to hide the content/site structure to public in AEM?

Tags: apache, aem, sling

We have our site built using AEM 6.5. The content structure is something like this- `/content/site/en`.

The issue that we are facing is that the content structure is visible in the google search. For example, if we search for denim, the results we get currently-

```
www.site.com/content/site/en/denim.html
```

The expected result-

```
www.site.com/denim.html
```

What could be the different options to hide the structure from the results? Thanks!

Comment: Hi, can I just ask why this bothers you? And do you have mutliple langues or is it just English? :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are looking for URL shortening. [This](https://shinesolutions.com/2017/01/04/demystifying-shortened-and-extension-less-urls-in-aem/) article talks exactly how todo for URL shortening.

**URL Shortening** - When content author curates an internal link using path picker, we want the respective anchor link href to get URL shortened and .html appended. Most common practice todo this is to use LinkRewriter. [This](https://helpx.adobe.com/experience-manager/using/aem63_link_rewriter.html) , [this](https://helpx.adobe.com/ca/experience-manager/kb/HowToConfigureLinkRewriting.html), [this](http://www.flexibledesigns.rs/creating-a-link-rewriter/) are different examples for same implementation. This will take care of changing from href=/content/site/en/denim.html to href=/en/denim.html. This is outgoing links.

**Resource resolution for incoming links** - Next we also need reverse also to happen. When someone hits a href=www.site.com/en/denim.html, we want AEM to resolve this to /content/site/en/denim page. To do this, there are (in general) 2 ways: 1) Using apache rewrite rules, 2) Sling Resource mapping. Another possible technique might be using CDN Edge rules, but I haven't seen anywhere for this.

A usual http request to AEM takes this route: browser -> CDN -> Apache -> AEM publisher. In this path, we can convert /denim.html to /content/site/en/denim at Apache or AEM

**Apache rewrite rules**: when request reaches apache, we use [mod_rewrite](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html) module to rewrite incoming traffic to AEM resolvable path. For example a simple rule `RewriteRule ^/en/(.*) /content/site/en/$1 [PT]` will change /en/denim./html to /content/site/en/denim.html. Refer [here](https://docs.adobe.com/content/help/en/experience-manager-dispatcher/using/configuring/dispatcher-domains.html#aem-rewrites-incoming-urls).

- Apache will see -> /en/denim.html
- AEM will see -> /content/site/en/denim.html

So URL is already resolved to AEM understandable path. AEM publisher can easily resolve this path to resource and render.

**Sling mapping**: Second technique is keep apache a dumb cache machine, send traffic directly to publisher, and ask publisher to resolve.

- Apache will see -> /en/denim.html
- AEM will see -> /en/denim.html

In /etc/maps, we implement internalRedirectRules. AEM before it begins process request, it will lookup the sling mapping, resolve the incoming request to valid resource path and then begins render business.

Both techniques have pros and cons. But Apache rewrite is preferable coz AEM is already too busy with other rendering work.

Summary:

1. Build Link Rewriter - for outgoing links
2. Build rewrite rules/sling mapper - for incoming links.

Answer (score 1):

Resource mapping can help you achieve your goal of hiding the content structure to the outside world.

[Here](https://docs.adobe.com/content/help/en/experience-manager-64/deploying/configuring/resource-mapping.html) is link that might help you more.